# Adding Eclipse to Gnome Do

Tags: eclipse, gnome, ubuntu

I'm trying to make do without a start menu on my Lubuntu laptop, and have installed Gnome Do as my launcher of choice.

Everything has been working the way it should up to now, and I have to say that the launcher really does eliminate the need for a start menu.

Anyway, I recently installed Eclipse (the java ide) and I can't get it to show up in Gnome Do. Here's how I installed eclipse:

```
$ ...Download eclipse, obviously...
$ cd /opt
$ sudo tar xvfz ~/Downloads/eclipse-whatever.tar.gz
```

Then I created a launcher for use on the Lubuntu desktop:

```
$ lxshortcut -o ~/Desktop/eclipse
```

After some fiddling around I ended up with this file in my ~/Desktop folder:

eclipse.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
GenericName=Eclipse Java IDE
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Name[en_US]=Eclipse Java IDE
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Development
```

The icon shows up nicely on the Lubuntu desktop. I can click it, and eclipse launches as expected.

However, no matter what amount of tweaking and restarting of Gnome Do, I just can't get it to show Eclipse.

Strange thing is I have Firefox on the desktop, with pretty much the same contents in the desktop shortcut file, and this shows up just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out why this doesn't work, but searching around on google I found that many people were using a tool called alacarte to setup new menu items. So I threw away the eclipse.desktop file I had created and used alacarte to set up the launcher, and after having done that the problem was solved. I can now search for eclipse with Gnome Do.